# C# TFS API: CheckIn method in class Workspace - Meaning of returned result from the method

Tags: c#, tfs

I work with TFS API and now I need to show to user messages concerning to result from Workspace.CheckIn method.

```
 public int? CheckInPendingChanges(PendingChange[] pendingChanges, string comments)
    {
        using (TfsTeamProjectCollection pc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(ConstTfsServerUri)))
        {
            if (pc == null) return null;

            WorkspaceInfo workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(ConstDefaultFlowsTfsPath);
            Workspace workspace = workspaceInfo?.GetWorkspace(pc);
            try
            {
                int? result = workspace?.CheckIn(pendingChanges, comments);
                return result;
            }
            catch (CheckinException exception)
            {
                UIHelper.Instance.RunOnUiThread(() => MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Check in exception has happened", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error));
                return null;
            }
            catch (VersionControlException exception)
            {
                UIHelper.Instance.RunOnUiThread(() => MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Version Control Exception has happened", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error));
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

However I haven't found comprehensive information about that. I've just found out that it should return changeset's ID in the case it has been succeed. In addition, I found this post:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2006/09/18/vc-api-checkin-may-return-0/
It explains that CheckIn returns "0" if your files hasn't changes and TFS undone it.
But what does it means if it returns -1 and null?

Comment: Have you ever received these before? I would guess if pendingchanges was null or empty you could get null, don't think -1 would ever be a valid response.

Comment: I saw -1 through decompiler (in MS code). It's kind of "not fatal error".
Null should be too. I think so because they did return parameter nullable becaue of some reason. Didn't they?

Comment: I don't think null would represent error, just that there was nothing to be done. I wonder what's considered a non-fatal checkin error?

Answer (score 0):

Check **Remarks** of [Workspace.CheckIn Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb139038(v=vs.120).aspx):

Each check-in is an atomic operation. All changes are checked in, or none are. If the check-in is successful, this method returns a positive changeset number. If the set of pending changes for the check-in is null, the server tries to check in all changes in the workspace. However, this operation is not valid if any pending changes in the workspace are edits or adds, because content will not have been uploaded to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I haven't found exact explanation for negative result, Null and 0, even in MS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to information that was gathered from different sources, I show to a user different messages:

```
public int? CheckInPendingChanges(PendingChange[] pendingChanges, string comments)
    {
        using (TfsTeamProjectCollection pc = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(ConstTfsServerUri)))
        {
            if (pc == null) return null;

            WorkspaceInfo workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(ConstDefaultFlowsTfsPath);
            Workspace workspace = workspaceInfo?.GetWorkspace(pc);
            try
            {
                int? result = workspace?.CheckIn(pendingChanges, comments);
                return result;
            }
            catch (CheckinException exception)
            {
                UIHelper.Instance.RunOnUiThread(() => MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Check in exception has happened", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error));
                return null;
            }
            catch (VersionControlException exception)
            {
                UIHelper.Instance.RunOnUiThread(() => MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, "Version Control Exception has happened", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error));
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
```

1) If result is null or negative - I consider it as exception:

```
  if (result < 0||result == null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Check in has failed due to internal Error", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                                    MessageBoxImage.Error);
                            return;
                        }
```

2) If result is 0, I consider it as Undo has been executed:

```
if (0 == result)
                        {
                              MessageBox.Show("The version control server automatically undoed the pending changes due to attempt to check in files that haven’t changed.", "No changes have been detected in your check in", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                                MessageBoxImage.Information);
                            ChangeSourceControlOperation(SourceControlOperations.Undo, currentVm);
                        }
```

3). If result is positive, I consider that as successfull result from TFS:

```
 if (result > 0)
   {
      //TODO: show changeset id or what ever                      
   }
```

Correct me if I wrong.